# What are some resources regarding the complexity of training neural networks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, time-complexity, complexity-theory

In the paper "[Provable bounds for learning some deep representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6343)", an autoencoder like a model is constructed with discrete weights and several results are proven using some random-graph theory, but I never saw any papers similar to this. i.e bounds on neural networks using random graph assumptions.

*What are some resources (e.g. books or papers) regarding the time and space complexity of training neural networks?*

I'm particularly interested in convolutional neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few technical papers and books on the topic

- [Computational Limitations on Learning from Examples](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.6387&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1988) by Leonard Pitt and Leslie G. Valiant, published in Journal of the ACM
- [Training a 3-node neural network is NP-complete](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608005800103) (1992) by Avrim L. Blum and Ronald L. Rivest, published in Neural Networks
- [Computational complexity of neural networks: a survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.7434&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1994) by Pekka Orponen, published in Nordic Journal of Computing
- [On the relative time complexities of standard and conjugate gradient backpropagation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/374143) (1994) by J. V. Stone and R. Lister, published in IEEE
- [Neural Networks - A Systematic Introduction](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/) (1996), specifically chapter 10 [The Complexity of Learning](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K10.pdf), a book by Raul Rojas
- [Complexity Analysis of Multilayer Perceptron Neural Network Embedded into a Wireless Sensor Network](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82200790.pdf) (2014) by Gursel Serpen and Zhenning Gao, published in Complex Adaptive Systems
- [On the Computational Efficiency of Training Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5267-on-the-computational-efficiency-of-training-neural-networks.pdf) (2014) by Roi Livni, Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Ohad Shamir, published in NIPS 2014
- [Convolutional Neural Networks at Constrained Time Cost](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/He_Convolutional_Neural_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) (2014) Kaiming He and  Jian Sun, published in IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (2015)
- [Learning Neural Networks with Two Nonlinear Layers in Polynomial Time](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06010.pdf) (2018) by Surbhi Goel and Adam Klivans

However, note that gradient descent (and other optimization algorithms) and the [back-propagation algorithm](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bhiksha/courses/deeplearning/Fall.2016/pdfs/Werbos.backprop.pdf) are [numerical algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) (that is, they deal with numerical errors), so the time complexity is not the only factor affecting the actual performance of these algorithms and models.